# Ocultar menu 1 ao abrir menu 2

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

Como faço para esconder o "MENU 1" ao abrir o "MENU 2"?

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo para uso em uma página limitada a CSS e HTML, porém quando aplicado na página ao abrir o "MENU 2" o "MENU 1" abre junto, preciso que ao passar o mouse seja aberto apenas um menu da cada vez:

```
<h1>2022</h1>
<div></div>
<style><!--
.MENU1 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.SUBMENU1 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1:hover .SUBMENU1 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.MENU2 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.SUBMENU2 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2:hover .SUBMENU2 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
--></style>
<div class="dropdown1"><button class="MENU1">Abril</button>
<div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">04/04 EVENTO 01</a></div>
<div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">10/04 EVENTO 02</a></div>
<div></div>
<div class="dropdown2"><button class="MENU2">Maio</button>
<div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">08/05 EVENTO 03</a></div>
<div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">15/05 EVENTO 04</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

agora abre apenas 1 menu , porem nao esta muito bom ao abrir o segundo menu com o menu1 aberto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>2022</h1>
<div></div>
<style><!--
.MENU1 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU1 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1:hover .SUBMENU1 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;


}
.MENU2 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2 {
   width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU2 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2:hover .SUBMENU2 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
   
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
--></style>
<div .flex>
    <div class="dropdown1">
        <button class="MENU1">Abril</button>
        <div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">04/04 EVENTO 01</a></div>
        <div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">10/04 EVENTO 02</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown2">
        <button class="MENU2">Maio</button>
        <div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">08/05 EVENTO 03</a></div>
        <div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">15/05 EVENTO 04</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, super me ajudou, fiz apenas alguns ajustes para a apresentação ficar melhor:

Adicionei no CSS .flex a direção horizontal, ficando assim:
```
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```
E adicionei uma class pq não estava reconhecendo a marcação .flex no html, ficando assim:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="dropdown1">
        <button class="MENU1">Abril</button>
        <div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">04/04 EVENTO 01</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Código com os ajustes realizados, deixando o Menu na horizontal e funcionando para abrir apenas um menu de cada vez:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>2022</h1>
<div></div>
<style><!--
.MENU1 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU1 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU1:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown1:hover .SUBMENU1 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;


}
.MENU2 {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width: 200px
}
.MENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2 {
   width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU2 {
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.SUBMENU2:hover{
background:#48D1CC;
color:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
    }
.dropdown2:hover .SUBMENU2 {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
   
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
--></style>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="dropdown1">
        <button class="MENU1">Abril</button>
        <div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">04/04 EVENTO 01</a></div>
        <div class="SUBMENU1"><a href="url">10/04 EVENTO 02</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown2">
        <button class="MENU2">Maio</button>
        <div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">08/05 EVENTO 03</a></div>
        <div class="SUBMENU2"><a href="url">15/05 EVENTO 04</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).